# Nginx - Error Log still being shown

Tags: nginx, logging

I have defined in my `server` block

```
location = /wp-login.php {deny all;access_log off;log_not_found off;}
```

However I am still seeing error messages being logged:

```
2018/11/03 19:00:53 [error] 6477#6477: *33405 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx216.150, server: , request: "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
Host: domain  Name: /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

How could I remove these messages from spamming the error.log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the client's perspective, a solitary `deny all;` is effectively the same as a `return 403;`, but without the "access forbidden by rule" error message.

For example:

```
location = /wp-login.php {
    return 403;
    access_log off;
}
```